# how to check list of application running in core in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cpu, operating-systems, intel-core-i3

I need to know list of application (.exe) running on single core (cpu) in windows 
for e.g

cmd.exe (application) is running on 2th core

Comment: I can't answer your question what tool can show this. But: applications are not running on a core. The threads of an application is running on a core. The most applications are multithreaded due to be able to run on different cores at the same time. So when you have four cores in a system and an application has four ore more threads, then it is possible that each thread is running on a different core.